# Why are the line endings different in every OS?

Tags: operating-system, cross-platform, line-endings

Windows has a certain format, and if a file is to be used in Linux, the line endings have to be converted. Isn't the line ending just a character like any other? Why is it treated specially?

Comment: Windows uses 2 characters "carriage return" and "line feed", Just like the 2 operations on your typewriter. Linux only uses one character thus breaking the whole computer/typewriter similarity...

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a variety of ways to indicate a record. Most operating systems used to support records with a line count. The first 2 or 4 bytes specified the length of the record. In fact, the Unix alternatives of the 70's-90's often supported indexing and random access.

Unix used dumbed-down system (great for simplicity) of just using a line-feed character to indicate record breaks.

This requires the terminal driver (or application) to convert the `<LF>` character into a `<CR><LF>` pair for display. Otherwise typing a file would give

```
Line 1
       Line 2
              Line 3
```

Rather than

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

MS-DOG went even simpler than Unix and adopted the convention of using a `<CR><LF>` pair to mark the end of records. No translation needed to type a file.